# Google Custom Search API start=100 causes error 400

Tags: php, google-custom-search

I have a script that uses Google Custom Search API, iterating through multiple results pages.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[[KEY]]&num=10&hl=en&start=0&cx=[[CX]]&q=%22bank%22&sort=date&googlehost=www.google.com

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[[KEY]]&num=10&hl=en&start=10&cx=[[CX]]&q=%22bank%22&sort=date&googlehost=www.google.com

https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[[KEY]]&num=10&hl=en&start=20&cx=[[CX]]&q=%22bank%22&sort=date&googlehost=www.google.com
```

In all of the above examples, I get proper responses. The query response claims that there are 17,900 results to the search.
When the script reaches start=100, however:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=[[KEY]]&num=10&hl=en&start=100&cx=[[CX]]&q=%22bank%22&sort=date&googlehost=www.google.com
```

I receive the following response (this is the JSON response transformed into a PHP object):

```
stdClass Object (
        [error] => stdClass Object
            (
                [errors] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [domain] => global
                                [reason] => invalid
                                [message] => Invalid Value
                            )
                    )
                [code] => 400
                [message] => Invalid Value
            ) )
```

This is despite the fact that the results I receive in start=90 claim that the next page exists:

```
"nextPage": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - \"bank\"",
    "totalResults": "17900",
    "searchTerms": "\"bank\"",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 100,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "[[CX VALUE]]",
    "sort": "date",
    "googleHost": "www.google.com",
    "hl": "en"
   }
  ]
```

Playing around with the API shows that this invalid value error appears exactly when start=92.
Furthermore, this is the exact page where this error appears for every keyword search.
Any help with the issue would be appreciated. Is this because this is a free version of Google Custom Search?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This info is not at all easy to find, and I found it mentioned officially in only one place on google.com.  I found a single line in [the Custom Search JSON API docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest#search_request_metadata) describing the `nextPage` response element:

> **Note**: This API returns up to the first 100 results only.

There is no mention of this being limited to the free API only.  I also found user reports confirming that the limit applies even if you sign up for billing, eg see [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853432/google-custom-search-engine-pricing) and [the linked blog post](https://alexjordanseniorproject.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/upgrading-your-custom-search-engine-be-careful/).

OTOH [the 100 *queries*/day limit](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview#pricing) (as opposed to the *results* limit you are seeing) is well documented, and there is info about how to bypass that everywhere (by signing up for billing, of course).